# Printing from a servlet spools forever

Tags: java, servlets, printing

Java is such a big world, but if you are printing to a paper... you are alone !!!

I have developed a software for accounting (invoices, etc...) since 2005, so it is quite stable now, except the printing part (it has ups and downs).

A few days ago, printing stopped completly and I have an endless spooling

If I call the API method to print "printInvoice(id)" from a simple java program (using command line) everything works perfect, and prints perfectly!

But If I call the same method from a servlet (tecnically is a Struts action), I get an endless spooling... no exceptions whatsoever

the code:

// this works

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    InvoiceServices is = InvoiceServices.getInstance();
    is.printInvoice(100);
}
```

// this does NOT works

```
public ActionForward execute(
        ActionMapping map, 
        ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest req, 
        HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {

    // this is the very same code above
    InvoiceServices is = InvoiceServices.getInstance();
    is.printInvoice(100);

    return stuff...
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why ? I have done a lot of testing and trial/error... already updated software... etc..

NOTE: this software is in a standalone PC